# Implementing generics for java 1.6

Tags: java, generics, java-6

I'm trying to make this code generic:

```
 public final Object unwrap(Class arg0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

It comes from the Wrapper class (java.sql) and looks originally like this:

```
<T> T unwrap(java.lang.Class<T> iface) throws java.sql.SQLException;
```

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Oh, the *actual* problem was thus to-tal-ly *not* related to generics. You should have copypasted the exact compilation error message and chosen a better title to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) throws SQLException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

which is exactly the same is the definition you pasted.

Comment: many thanks... throwing the SQLException is not necessary at this point.